# Does the set of Goldbach numbers have positive density?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

We say that an integer $n > 1$ is a *Goldbach number* if $n$ is the sum of two primes. The famous [Goldbach conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) says that every even integer greater than $2$ is Goldbach.

Consider the following much weaker statement:

> (G') The set $G$ of Goldbach numbers satisfies $\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}\frac{|G\cap\{1,\ldots,n+1\}|}{n+1} > 0$.

Is (G') true?

Comment: To add to Stanley Yao Xiao's answer, the fact that $G(x)=(1/2+o(1))x$ (enough to answer your question) was first proved by Vinogradov in the 1930s.

Comment: @ThomasBloom I think that this was proved by Chudakov (1937), Estermann (1938), van der Corput (1938).

Comment: Please make some minimal research before asking a question. For example, the answer to your question can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Way more than that is true. We have $G(x) = |G \cap [1,x]|$ satisfying

$$\displaystyle G(x) = \frac{x}{2} + O(x^{0.72}),$$

by a theorem of Janos Pintz. See this paper:https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.09084.pdf